# Failing to bitblt() to the centre of a transparent window c++/winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

When I bitblt onto my transparent window, a bmp smaller than the client area, it draws a fussy surrounding area instead of transparent like the set colorkey from:

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(0,255,0), 120, LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA); //colorkey & win alpha
```

The blit looks like this:

[image: gray background that should be transparent]

The candle-like test image makes its own area transparent like it should, but the surrounding client area gets grayed out according to the window-alpha value (120). Any ideas how to fix this? I've tried:

```
SetBkColor(hdc, crKey); and generating a background with
FillRect(background_hdc, &background_rect, hbrush); and blitting that first
```

Where neither work.

I have the feeling this should be alot easier than I'm making it out to be, and I still feel something like `SetBkColor(hdc,crKey);` should do the trick, but it doesnt. Maybe there is a similar command that does that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it funny how you solve the problem just after you formulate it properly?

Obviously the `hbrBackground` in the `WNDCLASSEX wc;`

defines the background of the window. So by setting the brush background when registering the window like so:

`wc.hbrBackground=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(240, 20, 120)); //COLORREF==crKey`

it gets crKey cancelled out during the blit along with the bmps crKey color. Thanks.

[image: working result]

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is correct. I can't see why the class brush would have any effect on `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Basically this lets you set the respective windows background to match that of the bmp/blitsource, and then turn both transparent with the `LWA_COLORKEY` in  the `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` call. Effectively creating a transparent background and image.

Comment: Ok so you're saving yourself the trouble of calling `FillRect` to fill in the color key. I still think that's a long bow to draw to link the class brush with `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`.

Comment: I couldnt get fillrect to work properly. This only requires a `SetClassLongPtr` for the  hbrBackground, and for it to match the colorkey in  `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`. I think its a good solution